# Why does Node.js/Express not accept connections from localhost?

Tags: node.js, express, networking

I encountered this strange behavior today I could not find a cause for. I am using MacOS Sierra.

I have this code (Express):

```
app.server.listen(config.port, config.address, function () {
    logger.info('app is listening on', config.address + ':' + config.port);
});
```

And it prints

```
app is listening on 127.0.0.1:5000
```

How ever, if I try to `curl`, it fails.

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/api/ping
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I checked my hosts file:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

So I ping localhost to make sure it resolves to `127.0.0.1`:

```
$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.126 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.135 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.061/0.107/0.135/0.033 ms
```

I try again, but it fails

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/api/ping
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Now I try to use `127.0.0.1` instead and voila, it works?

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/ping
pong
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Would you mind to post the contents of you /etc/hosts file? It seems to me that `localhost` may be incorrectly mapped there. This could cause this kind of error.

Comment: Is IPv6 enabled on your network adaptor? Curl might be trying to connect via IPv6 but the server isn't listening on that address.

Comment: Yes, my network adapter is IPv6 enabled, looking at ifconfig

Comment: Try using the option `-4` in the curl command.

Comment: Yep, that works now ```$ curl -4 http://localhost:5000/api/ping
pong```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cURL is trying to connect via IPv6 but your Express server is listening on 127.0.0.1 which is IPv4.

You can force cURL to connect via IPv4 with the `-4` option.

```
curl -4 http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/ping
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That was the issue!